# Axiom of Choice : Two Different Representation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, axiom-of-choice

### **Below is the proof of equivalence between two different statements of Axiom of Choice**

Axiom of Choice Statement 1 :

$f:X  \mapsto Y$ is onto $\Rightarrow \exists g:Y \mapsto X$ s.t. $f\circ g= 1_Y$

Axiom of Choice Statment 2:

Let $\Bbb{P}$ be a partition of X. $\exists g:\Bbb{P} \mapsto X$ for every $A \in \Bbb{P}$ s.t. $ g(A) \in A$

Axiom of Choice Statment 3:

For given $X$, $\exists h: 2^X\setminus \{\emptyset\}\rightarrow X$ s.t. $h(A) \in A$ for each $A \in 2^X\setminus \{\emptyset\}$

Axiom of Choice Statment 4:

$\prod_{i\in I}X_i \neq \emptyset $ if $I\neq \emptyset$ and $X
_i\neq$ for $ \forall i\in I$

---

**Claim:** Statement 1 $\Rightarrow$ Statement2

Let $\Bbb{P}$ be a partition of X. Then $A$ is uniquely given for each $x \in X$ s.t.  $x \in A \in \Bbb P $

Let this unique-given be $f : X \mapsto \Bbb P$

This $f$ is $onto$ since every $A \in \Bbb P$ and there $\exists$ at least one $x \in X$ since $\Bbb P$ is partition

Now, from the Statement 1, since $f$ is $onto$, $\exists g:\Bbb P \mapsto X$ s.t. $f\circ g= 1_\Bbb P$

Since $f \circ g (A) = A$, $g(A) \in A $ thus,

$\exists g:\Bbb{P} \mapsto X $ for every $A \in \Bbb{P}  $ s.t. $ g(A) \in A$

---

**Claim:** Statement 2 $\Rightarrow$ Statement1

$f:X  \rightarrow Y$ is onto $\Rightarrow \Bbb P:= \{f^{-1}(\{y\})\mid y \in Y\}$ be a partition of $X$. Thus

$\exists g: \Bbb P \rightarrow X$ s.t. $g[\{f^{-1}(\{y\})] \in f^{-1}(\{y\})$

Define $h: Y \rightarrow X $ s.t. $h(y):=g[f^{-1}(\{y\})]$ then

$f(h(y))=y$ since $h(y) = f^{-1}(\{y\})$

---

**Claim:** Statement 2 $\Rightarrow$ Statement 3

Define $\widetilde{A} := \{(A,a) \mid a \in A\}\subset (2^X\setminus\{\emptyset\}) \times X$  then

$\Bbb P = \{\widetilde{A}\mid A\in 2^X\setminus\{\emptyset\}\}$ be a partition of

$Y =\cup\{\widetilde{A}\mid A\in 2^X\setminus\{\emptyset\}\}$ thus

$\exists g: \Bbb P \rightarrow Y s.t. g(\widetilde{A})\in \widetilde{A}$ for each $A \in 2^X\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ ( Statement 2)

Now there $\exists h: A\rightarrow \pi_2(g(\widetilde{A})), A\in2^X\setminus\{\emptyset\} $ s.t.
$\pi_2 : (2^X\setminus\{\emptyset\})\times X \rightarrow X$

---

**Claim:** Statement 3 $\rightarrow$ Statement 2

It is true since a partition $\Bbb P \subset  2^X\setminus\{\emptyset\}$

---

**Claim:** Statement 3 $\rightarrow$ Statement 4

Let $X = \cup_{i\in I}X_i$ and $g: I \rightarrow X$ be $g(i)=h(X_i)$

then $g(i)=h(X_i) \in X$ for  $h: 2^X\setminus \{\emptyset\}\rightarrow X$

---

**Claim:** Statement 4 $\rightarrow$ Statement 3

$\prod \{A\mid A\in 2^X\setminus \{\emptyset\}\} \neq \emptyset $

Let $h \in \prod \{A\mid A\in 2^X\setminus \{\emptyset\}\}$ then
$h(A) \in A$

---

It concludes that abvoe 4 statments logically equivalent.

Any illogical part in this proof?

Comment: Does "is onto" mean surjective?

Comment: Yes it means surjective

Comment: I see no problem with the proof. But you should *really* write it like "There is a mapping $g:\Bbb P\to X$ s.t. for all $A\in\Bbb P$ it holds $g(A)\in A$" because otherwise you state that there could be a different $g$ for every $A\in\Bbb P$. This would be trivial. The order of quantifiers matter!

Comment: updated as you commented.

Comment: Just a typesetting comment: Normally $\mapsto$ is used for the value of a function at some argument; to say that $f$ is a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$, one writes $f\colon A\to B$. Also, what do you mean by "the partition" of $X$, there is no such thing. Do you mean "Let $\mathbb P$ be a partition of $X$"? (I would really write it as "For any partition ...")

Comment: Yes I meam "a" partition

Comment: The second part of the proof is also fine, so I'm not going to change my answer.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila If I edit the body, person who answered  get notified? It's an irrelevant question but just wander about the SE system.

Comment: Nope. I just saw the question was edited, and came to see.

Comment: @AsafKaragila got it. Will add 2 more statement of Axiom of Choice. Hope you proof-reading if you have a chance&time. And also one of the main reason that I separated at first because of the inconvenience of editing system. If you know any Mathjax Editor that is view-able half_typed_in&half_rendered of the browser, please let me know.

Comment: please check_ it's updated with 2 more equivalent statement.

Comment: A style often seen in books is to prove $(1)\to (2)\to (3)\to (4)\to (1).$... For $(4)\to (1)$, let $X_y=f^{-1}\{y\}$ for $y\in Y$ and let $g\in \prod_{y\in Y}X_y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is mathematically sound.

The key point to notice here is that every partition of $X$ induces a set $Y$ and a surjection from $X$ onto $Y$; and every function with domain $X$ induces a partition of $X$ as well (and every function is onto its range). This is why these two are equivalent.

For a nice additional statement, show that every equivalence relation $E$ on a set $X$ has some $R\subseteq X$ such that every $x\in X$ is $E$-equivalent to exactly one element of $R$. (The key here is to notice that equivalence relations and partitions are "morally the same".)